# Does the Lazy class clear the reference to the factory delegate after having generated the value?

Tags: c#

Consider the following C# code using MemoryCache to generate a new value for a given key if not already preset in the cache:

```
private static MemoryCache _memoryCache = new MemoryCache();

public T Apply<T>(string key, Func<T> factory)
{
    var expiration ...

    var newValue = new Lazy<T>(factory);
    var value = (Lazy<T>)_memoryCache.AddOrGetExisting(key, newValue, expiration);
    return (value ?? newValue).Value;
}
```

Consider now this:

```
var hugeObject = new HugeObject();

return cache.Apply("SomeKey", () =>
{
    return hugeObject.GetValue();
});
```

The factory will be invoked "immediately" after AddOrGetExisting or never, so the question is:

**Does the Lazy class clear the reference to the factory delegate after having generated the value (so all the resources used by the factory like, in this case, hugeObject, can be released)?**

Comment: Disposal is very different from holding onto a reference to it.  You dispose of disposable resources, of which a delegate is not.

Comment: You can literally look at the code for [`Lazy<T>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Lazy.cs)

Comment: @Servy Sorry, I meant it in a broad sense (remove the reference to it so that the GC can free the memory) like I'm doing in _factory = null;

Comment: @drevis But disposal has a very specific meaning in the context of a C# program, and that doesn't fit it.

Comment: @Servy Fine, changed

Comment: Your `LazyCacheItem<T>` class has less sophisticated error handling than `Lazy<T>`, as well as not supporting `LazyThreadSafetyMode`.  If your factory method throws an exception, it will be called repeatedly whenever Value is dereferenced.  Whereas `Lazy<T>` will save and throw the same exception each time.

Comment: @Joe, thanks, I'm well aware of that, in fact I shouldn't have posted it before getting an answer to the first question :p

Comment: @Joe I've never once come across a situation where the exception caching was desirable.  It's only ever been something I've had to work around when using `Lazy`.

Comment: @Servy, YMMV of course, and if you don't want exception caching you can use LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly

Comment: @Joe But then you lose thread safety, which is the primary purpose of using `Lazy` in the first place.  It doesn't provide a useful, thread safe way of ensuring an object is initialized exactly once unless that operation can't ever possibly fail.  If it can fail, you can't use `Lazy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Lazy.cs,368), I believe it does release the factory, and call out why:

```
// We successfully created and stored the value.  At this point, the value factory delegate is
// no longer needed, and we don't want to hold onto its resources.
m_valueFactory = ALREADY_INVOKED_SENTINEL;
```

There is quite a lot of threading code in there so I'm not sure it does so every time, but you'd hope that if they've realise they need to, they will have done so properly.

Comment: You know you can click the line numbers on the reference source site and get a [link that takes people to the exact lines your quoting](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Lazy.cs,368)?

Comment: Thanks Rawling, they should indeed, I'll keep using the first implementation then.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I do now!